# Analysis of MCMC output to choose batch size for thinning

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo

How do we interpret trace and kernel density plots as output from MCMC algorithms? Is it possible to determine from these a possible batch size for thinning?

Comment: thinning is deprecated unless necessary for (unusual) memory reasons.

Comment: Reinforcing @carlo comment, you should only thin if storing or processing your MCMC output is computationally burdensome. Otherwise, thinning is *always* inefficient.